# Where do I put the NLog.config file in a MAUI project?

Tags: c#, maui, nlog

We are currently starting to switch vom xamarin to maui. In the first steps, I wanted to implement logging via NLog. After some starting problems, I got it running for iOS. When I try to run it on Android, I get the exception "System.IO.FileNotFoundException".

Unfortunately there is nothing on the internet - at least not that I found. Maybe some of you guys could help me.

FYI: At the moment the NLog.config file is located at the root folder of the project.

(I know in Xamarin we had to put the NLog.Config file into the assets and that there is also a assets-folder for Android in Maui. I just hoped, that we don´t have to put the same file twice in one project..)

Comment: You probably need to add it as asset to your project. Does [something like this](https://www.xamarinhelp.com/configuration-files-xamarin-forms/) help?

Comment: Maybe put `NLog.config`-file into assembly-ressource and then use `NLog.LogManager.Setup()..LoadConfigurationFromAssemblyResource(typeof(App).Assembly)`. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Targets.MauiLog

Comment: Yeah, i also tried to put it in the assets folder and assembly-ressource. Unfortunately neither of these two works. 
One thing is still confusing me. Doesnt matter, where i put it, it works for iOS but not for android.. 
@RolfKristensen I already looked up on this link. The problem is, that in this project the set the config programatically and not via config-file. So it does not help me very much

Comment: @grabnerM You are loading NLog-configuration from `NLog.config`-file, when adding the `NLog.config` as assembly-resource, and using `LoadConfigurationFromAssemblyResource`. But happy you found an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured it out.
After trying several different spots where to put the config file and where to load it, I finally fount the correct spot for both.

Luckily it is possible to put the NLog.config-file directly in the root folder of the MAUI-project.
If you want to load the config file just use this statement in App() in the App.xaml.cs file. Therefor I used a method (we have a base-project which we inheritate)

```
protected override void InitializeLogger()
{
    LogManager.Setup().RegisterMauiLog().LoadConfigurationFromAssemblyResource(typeof(App).Assembly);
    _NLog = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
}
```

Works for Android and iOS and you don't have to specify anything in the AppDelegate.cs (iOS) or MainActivity.cs (Android) files.